# How to convert an Indexed pixel format image to a 32-bit image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, indexed-image

I have an image that I get and attempt to load into a graphics object using Graphics.FromImage(image), however this throws an exception if the image has an indexed pixel format.

Is there a way to safely convert an indexed image?

**Update:** Thanks to Joe for the tip to just draw the old image over the new one, instead I was trying to convert it. This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easy way is to create a new image of the same size (with a 32-bit pixel format). Then create a graphics object for *that* image and draw the original on top of it.

Answer (score -1):

what you can do is based on the indexes u can calculate the euclidian distance in the 3 channel color space. Then find the closest color and use those values for your new image.