# How to convert an indexed image to rgb image in C#?

Tags: c#, image-processing

hey , i want to convert an indexed image to rgb image in C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an Indexed pixel format image to a 32-bit image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848943/how-to-convert-an-indexed-pixel-format-image-to-a-32-bit-image)

Answer (score 1):

Use a palette (a sort of conversion table).
i.e.:

```
i  ->  R,G,B
0     255, 0, 0
1     254, 0, 0
2     253, 0, 0
3     252, 0, 0
4     251, 0, 0
.
.
260   0, 250, 0
.
.
.
```

etc